# Efficient cardinality of set overlap relation

Tags: sets, mathematical-foundations, set-cover, partial-order

Assume that we have a set `S` of sets `s`.

Every pair `(s,s')` in `SxS` can be overlapping or not.

How can we efficiently compute the number of pairs `(s,s')` that are overlapping, i.e. that share at least one element?

Additional: actually each set `s` occurs a number of times (`S` is a multiset). I have tried to create a matrix `M` of `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` that stores the subset partial order over `S`. Then I have tried to add the additional edges for overlaps through `M.T.dot(M)` to then later compute `f.dot(M).dot(f.T)`, where `f` gives the frequency for each `s`. Unfortunately `M.T.dot(M)` becomes too large, so if anything, we probably have to propagate the counts through the subset partial order one after the other.

Hints: it might seem apparent at first to just take the sum over the union of all elements in all `s` of their frequency squared to sum up the number of pairs sharing one particular element. However the problem is that this counts many pairs multiple times. For example `{a,b}` is counted for `a` and also for `b`. This is why it seems important to use the subset partial order.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you interested in a theoretical or a practical solution? If the latter, can you please provide some statistics: how many distinct elements ($n$) exist and how many sets ($|S|$) do you have? There is a simple solution requiring $O(n \cdot |S|^2)$ time (for each element, sets containing this element form a pair). If it's not acceptable, then: how many pairs of sets have 2 (3, 4) common elements? If possible, can you provide a histogram for all possible numbers of common elements?

Comment: The *Orthogonal Vectors* problem asks whether *every* two sets are intersecting. Under reasonable assumptions, when the universe has size $O(\log n)$ and there are $n$ sets, then there are no algorithms running in time $O(n^{2-\epsilon})$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found a solution that is more on the practical side, although it should be possible to motivate it theoretically. I will enter this later and hope I got it right.

Comment: I also have one peculiarity that I forgot to mention as a special case and I think this allows to sped things up practically.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following problem. We are given $n$ sets $S_1,\ldots,S_n \subseteq \{1,\ldots,\log n\}$, and have to decide whether there are two disjoint sets among them. This problem is known as *Orthogonal Vectors* (OV), and it is conjectured that it cannot be solved in time $O(n^{2-\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$ (on a RAM machine). See for example Chen and Williams, [An Equivalence Class for Orthogonal Vectors](http://www.mit.edu/%7Elijieche/SODA_2019_OV-Equiv-Fullversion.pdf).